# Membership provider with different ApplicationName in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-membership

I have a `web.config` in my MVC3 application, I have an `Admin` area in my MVC3 application too.

On the front end I hook asp.net users into a `Customers` table and my application relies on this  table to operate. In the `Admin` area I have an `Administrator Role` and `User` but this login also works for the front end. I can create a customer for my `Admin` so my application doesn't fail but ideally I would like to separate the logins from the front and `Admin` area.

I want to put a second `web.config` inside my `Admin` area that has a different application name so that the Admin account can never be logged into the front end. e.g.

```
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="SecurityConn" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
```

But I don't know where to put this or if it is even possible

```
applicationName="/AdminArea"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add more than one provider in the  section with different applicationname.

What you will need to consider is how you would switch between those providers.
You can use the providers collection e.g.

```
Membership.Providers["MyOtherProvider"].ValidateUser(username, pwd);
```

So you will need a mechanism to know who is logging in (Admin or customer).

Comment: ...I can do this because they use different login forms, and if logging in on the frontend fails I can always check the admin provider using this code... Brilliant! mucho más grandes gracias!

Comment: I've only recently got round to trying this out. The problem still remains I cannot log into the Backend and Frontend simultaneously. My main concern is now making sure `Membership.Providers["MyOtherProvider"]` cannot access the front end...

Comment: May be things are not clear to me. Why would you need two separate login pages then when you are using Roles to differentiate the users. Although you can have different login providers but share same roles if that's going to work in your case.